# Route restrict access for current user

Tags: 8, routes, users

How do I restrict access to the route by current user in Drupal 8?

I want to create a new tab in user profile `path: '/user/{user}/my-cool-tab'`, which should be accessible by current user only. For example:

- path `/user/5/my-cool-tab` should be available only for UID=5
- path `/user/7/my-cool-tab` should be available only for UID=7
- etc.

Which way is the simplest and correct for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an access check where you compare the passed user id with the current user, here's an example from simplenews:

```
public function checkAccess(UserInterface $user) {
  $account = $this->currentUser();

  return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'administer simplenews subscriptions')
    ->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'subscribe to newsletters')
      ->andIf(AccessResult::allowedIf($user->id() == $account->id())));
}
```

Note that this includes and admin permission check, for admins that can actually see the page for other users.

If you do not need that, you could also just make your route /my-cool-page and use the current user for whatever you are doing. With D8's routing system, you can even make local task appear on the user page if you want to.

Comment: I thought there is some standard way to achieve that, because it looks very common situation as for me.. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to see full details how to achieve such case.

Route Path with custom access checking function

```
path: '/user/{user}/my-cool-tab'
...
requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\AccessCheck::myRoutePermission'
```

Create new controller which specifically check the accesses.

```
mymodule/src/Controller/AccessCheck.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Access Checks controller.
 */
class AccessCheck extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The request stack.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The current user.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * The controller constructor.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request_stack
   *   The request stack.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $current_user
   *   The current user.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, AccountInterface $current_user) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->currentUser = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->load($current_user->id());
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('request_stack'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Checks access for __ route.
   */
  public function myRoutePermission() {
    $uid = $this->requestStack->attributes->get('user_id');
    if ($this->currentUser->hasPermission('administer users')) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
    elseif ($uid != $this->currentUser->id()) {
      // Return 403 Access Denied page.
      return AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }

}
```

This way you can add any number of access checking function with any type of checks.